# Why is Loker looking for a job?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, lie-to-me

In season 3 of *Lie to Me* we can watch that Eli Loker is looking for a job. In addition, he hires a deaf person to take Loker's place... Why does Cal Lightman suddenly not want him anymore in the Lightman Group?